# Loop in string and get word between 2 character

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-routing

i have string like:

```
www.sample.com/cat-phone/cat-samsung/attrib-1_2/attrib-2_88/...
```

how to get last category , in this example , cat-samsung.
and how to get 1_2 and 2_88 and ... and split 1 from 2 or 2 from 88.

i write this code to get value between / and / .

```
public void GetCodesAndPrice(string url,out List<int> listOfCodes, out List<int> listOfPrice )
{
    listOfCodes=new List<int>();
    listOfPrice = new List<int>();
    url = url.Substring(url.IndexOf('?')+1);
    var strArray = url.Split('/');
    foreach (string s in strArray)
    {
        if(s.ToLower().Contains("code"))
            listOfCodes.Add(GetIntValue(s));

        else if(s.ToLower().Contains("price"))
            listOfPrice.Add(GetIntValue(s));
    }

    // Now you have list of price in "listOfPrice" and codes in "listOfCodes",
    // If you want to return these two list then declare as out

}
public int GetIntValue(string str)
{
    try
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(str.Substring(str.IndexOf('-') + 1));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        // Handle your exception over here
    }
    return 0; // It depends on you what do you want to return if exception occurs in this function
}
```

this code work for get integer values . but i can,t get latest category , in this example , samsung. i want to get samung name and then convert value to id in the next operation.

Comment: What have you tried doing so far?  What problems have you had with those attempts?

Comment: Do you have anything written so far?

Comment: Are you trying to manually handle routing?

Answer (score 0):

There are some string function/method, which helps you to achieve your goal.

First is [`String.Substring(startindex, length)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Second is [`String.Split("symbol")`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split)

For Example:

```
string your_String = "www.sample.com/cat-phone/cat-samsung/attrib-1_2/attrib-2_88/";
string last_Cat = your_String.Substring((your_String.LastIndexOf("cat-") - 1), (your_String.IndexOf("attrib-") - 2));
   Console.WriteLine(last_Cat);
  for (int i = 0; i < your_String.Split("/").Length; i++) {
    if (your_String.Split("/")[i].ToString().IndexOf("attrib-") != -1) {
        strin attri += your_String.Split("/")[i].Split("-")[1].Split("_")[1].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(all_attri);
    }
  }
```

(This is only an example to show you, how can you use these function in string manipulation.)

Comment: doesn't work for me . i want to get cat-samsung . and end of string can any word

Answer (score 0):

*Regular Expressions* are your friend here. They're made for slicing and dicing text. Here's a class that will do what you need:

```
class MyDecodedUri
{
  // regex to match strings like this: /cat-phone/cat-samsung/attrib-1_2/attrib-2_88/...
  const string PathSegmentRegex = @"
    /                      # a solidus (forward slash), followed by EITHER
    (                      # ...followed by EITHER
      (?<cat>              # + a group named 'cat', consisting of
        cat                #   - the literal 'cat' followed by
        -                  #   - exactly 1 hyphen, followed by
        (?<catName>\p{L}+) #   - a group named 'catName', consisting of one or more decimal digits
      ) |                  # OR ...
      (?<attr>             # + a group named 'attr', consisting of
        attrib             #   - the literal 'attrib', followed by
        -                  #   - exactly 1 hyphen, followed by
        (?<majorValue>\d+) #   - a group named 'majorValue', consisting of one or more decimal digits, followed by
        _                  #   - exactly one underscore, followed by
        (?<minorValue>\d+) #   - a group named 'minorValue', consisting of one or more decimal digits
      )                    #
    )                      #
    " ;
  static Regex rxPathSegment = new Regex( PathSegmentRegex , RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture|RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace ) ;

  public MyDecodedUri( Uri uri )
  {
    Match[] matches = rxPathSegment.Matches(uri.AbsolutePath).Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Success ).ToArray() ;

    this.categories = matches
                      .Where(  m => m.Groups["cat"].Success )
                      .Select( m => new UriCategory( m.Groups["catName"].Value ) )
                      .ToArray()
                      ;

    this.attributes = matches
                      .Where( m => m.Groups["attr"].Success )
                      .Select( m => new UriAttribute( m.Groups["majorValue"].Value , m.Groups["minorValue"].Value ) )
                      .ToArray()
                      ;

    return ;
  }

  private readonly UriCategory[] categories ; 
  public UriCategory[] Categories { get { return (UriCategory[]) categories.Clone() ; } }

  private readonly UriAttribute[] attributes ; 
  public UriAttribute[] Attributes { get { return (UriAttribute[]) attributes.Clone() ; } }

  public Uri RawUri { get ; private set ; }

}
```

It uses a couple of custom helper types, one for category and one for attribute:

```
struct UriCategory
{
  public UriCategory( string name ) : this()
  {
    if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) ) throw new ArgumentException("category name can't be null, empty or whitespace","name");
    this.Name = name ;
    return ;
  }

  public readonly string Name  ;

  public override string ToString() { return this.Name ; }

}

struct UriAttribute
{
  public UriAttribute( string major , string minor ) : this()
  {
    bool parseSuccessful ;

    parseSuccessful = int.TryParse( major , out Major ) ;
    if ( !parseSuccessful ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("major") ;

    parseSuccessful = int.TryParse( minor , out Minor ) ;
    if ( !parseSuccessful ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("minor") ;

    return ;
  }

  public readonly int Major  ;
  public readonly int Minor ;

  public override string ToString() { return string.Format( "{0}_{1}" , this.Major , this.Minor ) ; }

}
```

Usage is dead simple:

```
string url = "http://www.sample.com/cat-phone/cat-samsung/attrib-1_2/attrib-2_88/" ;
Uri uri = new Uri(url) ;
MyDecodedUri decoded = new MyDecodedUri(uri) ;
```

Comment: Hi Nicholas. Thank you for your answer. nut i don't know use of your class .